# If I change my router's IP address, why do all client devices assume it's at 192.168.1.1?

Tags: domain-name-system, router, wifi, ip-address

I've decided to set my router at some non "1.1" IP address.

I have even created a QR code for connecting to the Wi-Fi.

The problem is, it looks most devices assume that if the DNS address is not specified, it should be 192.168.1.1.

The router (gateway) acting as a DNS relay is supposed to speed up DNS lookup.

But I have yet to find a device that does not assume the "DNS" is not set-up at "192.168.1.1".

The result is that most devices require manual configuration for the DNS IP address, but the router already is supposed to provide that.

Comment: 1) The question is off-topic here. 2) It would really help to a least know *which* router you are talking about.

Comment: it's Huawei, but hard configured for a particular region, so that won't be much of help... Missing a lot of functions
Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DHCP server in the router must also reconfigured to reflect that change.

```
Default gateway -> new ip
DNS server -> new ip
```

The devices must also be configured to receive the DNS from DHCP.